# Orphan Objects in Java Good or Bad?

Tags: java, oop, object, memory-management, orphan

I want to understand the object creation best practices in Java Programming.
I have given an example below Please check and suggest me 
Orphan Objects in Java Good or Bad?

I have an `Shape` interface.

1. `Circle implements Shape`
2. `Square implements Shape`
3. `Cube implements Shape`
4. `Sphere implements Shape`

Approach #1 causes orphan objects, Approach #2 causes unnecessary references. Which approach is the best practice?

**Approach #1**

```
    Shape shape;
    shape = new Circle();  // CREATES CIRCLE OBJECT
    shape.draw();
    shape = new Cube();    // CREATES CUBE OBJECT
    shape.draw();
    shape = new Sphere();  // CREATES SPHERE OBJECT
    shape.draw();
    shape = new Square();  // CREATES SQUARE OBJECT
    shape.draw();
```

**Approach #2**

```
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    circle.draw();
    Cube cube = new Cube();
    cube.draw();
    Sphere sphere = new Sphere();
    sphere.draw();
    Square square = new Square();
    square.draw();
```

Comment: If your aim is to avoid orphaned objects, then the references created by approach #2 are, by definition, not unnecessary.

Comment: "best practice" by what measurment? It dependes on the context in which this code snippet is called. Generally speaking, the GC will take care.

Comment: personally i prefer second approach, as name of variables are clear and meaningful. And don;t worry about orphan object, garbage collector will handle them

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you create objects to accomplish some task, and when you are finished with them, you remove references to them so they are garbage collected. The number of references you have to these objects is rarely a performance issue; generally problems arise from:

1. creating too many objects when you could reuse them
2. you have bugs in cleaning up your references (memory leak).

Your primary concern should be how often you call `new`.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't need the objects after you have called their method `draw`, then it is ok to forget the references to them. They will become eligible for garbage collection and the memory they occupy will be recovered when the garbage collector does it job.

So if memory management is your concern, then "orphaning" objects is standard Java practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you just create the objects for one-time use, neither approach. Don't even assign the reference for a single call, just make the call directly:

```
new Circle().draw();
new Cube().draw();
new Sphere().draw();
...
```

Everything else is just confusing, holding a reference that you don't actually need for anything hinders readability.